# Xcode 4 project with external sources (without static library or framework)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is it possible just to use external sources without making static libraries or something else?
For instance, when I add some files header search path (which is located in the same workspace, so I use ../Project/Project) and add files I need to compile to 'compile sources' in Build phases tab, still got linking error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CallMe",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Answer (score 0):

You should add files by clicking on `File -> Add Files to "<your project>"` Xcode does the rest. It isn't necessary to edit the search paths.